# Getting Wrong bucket region error while streaming video in spring boot with client android

Tags: java, android, spring, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I am trying to create Video streaming app with backend in spring boot. I have created two apis for downloading video file and streaming video file.

For downloading video file

```
@PostMapping("/api/v1/downloadVideoAWS")
public ResponseEntity<ByteArrayResource> downloadFile(@RequestBody FileSnapshot fileSnapshot) {
    byte[] data = fileSnapshotService.downloadVideoAWS(fileSnapshot);
    ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(data);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().contentLength(data.length)
            .header("Content-type", "application/octet-stream")
            .header("Content-disposition", "attachement; filename=\"" + fileSnapshot.getFileName() + "\"")
            .body(resource);
}
```

its client request in android retrofit

```
@HTTP(method = "POST", hasBody = true,path = "/api/v1/downloadVideoAWS")
Call <ResponseBody> getVideoFile(@Body FileSnapshot fileSnapshot);
```

for streaming video file

```
@GetMapping(value = "/api/v1/streamVideo/**", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE })
public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> getObject(HttpServletRequest request) {
    try {

        String uri = request.getRequestURI();
        String uriParts[] = uri.split("/", 2)[1].split("/", 2);
        String bucket = uriParts[0];
        String key = uriParts[1];
        System.out.println("Fetching " + uri);
        AmazonS3 s3client = fileSnapshotService.getS3Client();
        S3Object object = s3client.getObject(bucket, key);
        S3ObjectInputStream finalObject = object.getObjectContent();

        final StreamingResponseBody body = outputStream -> {
            int numberOfBytesToWrite = 0;
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            while ((numberOfBytesToWrite = finalObject.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(data, 0, numberOfBytesToWrite);
            }
            finalObject.close();
        };
        return new ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody>(body, HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error "+ e.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

}
```

its client request in android retrofit

```
 @GET("/api/v1/streamVideo/{bucketName}/{fileName}")
Call<ResponseBody> getStreamingObject(@Path("bucketName") String bucketName,@Path("fileName")String fileName);
```

AmazonS3 client

```
@Bean
public AmazonS3 gennerateS3Client() {
    AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey,secretKey);
    return  AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
            .withRegion(regionCode)
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
            .build();

}
```

where regionCode = "ap-south-1";

now problem is that I am able to download video file without any issue .but when I am trying to stream video file from the API I am getting this error in spring boot

Error The bucket is in this region: eu-west-1. Please use this region to retry the request (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 301; Error Code: PermanentRedirect; Request ID: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX; S3 Extended Request ID: /XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=; Proxy: null)

please help me resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

It was a bucket Name issue due to this code

```
String uri = request.getRequestURI();
String uriParts[] = uri.split("/", 2)[1].split("/", 2);
String bucket = uriParts[0];
String key = uriParts[1];
```

,need to make sure bucket name is key is proper before accessing it